# Testing sequence of events with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I was just starting out with RSpec, and im trying to do something quite trivial, but I couldnt find any good documentation on a good way of doing this. I want to test a sequence of events, say the friendship between two users.

My spec is:

```
describe User do

  describe "friendships" do
    describe ".friends?" do
      before do
        @user1 = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
        @user2 = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
      end

      it "should be false for non friends" do
        @user1.friends?(@user2).should be false
        @user2.friends?(@user1).should be false
      end

      it "should be false for requested friendship" do
        Friendship.create(:user_id => @user1.id, :friend_id => @user2.id)  # 1
        @user1.friends?(@user2).should be false
        @user2.friends?(@user1).should be false
      end

      it "should be true for accepted friendship" do
        Friendship.for_users(@user1, @user2).update_attribute(:approved, true) # 2
        @user1.friends?(@user2).should be true
        @user2.friends?(@user1).should be true
      end
    end

  end
end
```

I am creating a friendship at the line marked `# 1`, and expect it to be present at line `# 2`, but I am guessing the database gets flushed in between the two.

Is this the wrong way of testing such a flow of events? What should I be doing? Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for `context`. Something like this:

```
context "when friends" do
  before { Friendship.create ... }

  it "should be false for requested friendship"

  it "should be true for accepted friendship"
end
```

Sorry to say that but you should probably take a look on rspec docs: [basic structure (describe/it)](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-10/docs/example-groups/basic-structure-describe-it)

Comment: In this case, do changes persist between the first it and the second it?

Comment: No. It's just the `before` block is executed for each example.

Comment: But as I mentioned in my question, the state of the friendship object changes in order to go from requested to accepted. How does context help in that case?

Comment: It changes in the `before` block, right? Which is executed before each example. Each example should be ran in isolation. It really doesn't make any sense to depend in one example on another.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, database gets flushed between the flow of events.

The best approach to testing is to have each test set up what it needs, and throw it away when it's done. That way each test is completely self contained, so you don't have to depend on previous tests for your later ones.

You may consider just building the friendship in factory girl and then testing that the friendship exists, and then make people friends through the UI in an integration test and check the same thing

Comment: Crap. I was so sure there was something I was missing.